# Wikitudeのビルド成功した方いますか？

Tags: monaca

お世話になっています。

現在ARツールのWikitudeを利用したアプリの開発に挑戦しており、
とりあえずサンプルのビルドを目指していますが、
Wikitudeのプラグインをインポートしてビルド（デバックビルド・リリースビルド両方試しました。）しただけでビルドでエラーが発生して困っています。

設定した内容は以下の通りです。

・ビルドを行ったOSは　今のところAndroidのみです。
・利用しているプラグインはwikitude以外は初期状態です
・Wikitudeのバージョンは4.1.0-3.1.0　です。（wikitude-cordova-plugin-4.1.0-3.1.0.zip）
・デバックビルド・リリースビルド両方試しました。
・WikitudePlugin.js 内　this._sdKeyはWikitudeの開発者画面にて取得したものを設定しました。

ビルド失敗後のエラーの対応のメッセージとして、
以下二つが表示されています。（画像を添付追加で添付します）

[image: Monaca Wikitudeビルド失敗時ダイアログ]

・AndroidManifest.xmlは正しく設定されていますか？
　　　→設定する項目がないので初期状態のままです

・キーストアの設定が正しいですか？
　　　→新規に作成した設定を使用しています。Wikitudeを利用しない場合は問題なくビルドできていることを確認しています。

Monaca環境内でWikitudeのビルドに成功したことがある方、
設定内容等教えていただけるとありがたいです。

以下がビルド時のログになります。

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------

Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 4.1
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.device-motion&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.camera&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.device-orientation&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.geolocation&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.network-information&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.vibration&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.contacts&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.splashscreen&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.device&quot; for android
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.media-capture&quot; for android
Fetching plugin &quot;org.apache.cordova.file&quot; via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.file
npm http 304 http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.file
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.file&quot; for android
Installing &quot;com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.

            Have fun using world&apos;s first AR plugin for PhoneGap. Visit http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap for detailed documentation for the plugin.

            Make sure that you enter your Wikitude SDK trial license key in `WikitudePlugin.js` line 12. If you havent bought a license please visit http://www.wikitude.com/store.

            If you want to contribute to the open source project, please visit us at github, http://github.com/Wikitude

Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/hooks/after_prepare/monaca_enterprise_encrypt.js /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton
Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build --release
Buildfile: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with &apos;release&apos;...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 93 source files to /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo]
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar:/private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/libs/wikitudesdk.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 33 source files to /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [javac] /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:756: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method getView()
    [javac] location: class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    [javac]         ((CordovaWebView)rootView).getView().clearFocus();
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:771: handleResume(boolean,boolean) in org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView cannot be applied to (boolean)
    [javac]             ((CordovaWebView)rootView).handleResume(true);
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 7 seconds

/private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: release,-f,/private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /private/tmp/monaca/55bedcb5fd1734496d554ef5/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
Build error: Error building project source code

//--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @Sieg 返答ありがとうございました。助言に従い、設定の説明を追加しました。

Comment: 私が使用しているWikitudeのバージョンより1つ新しいですね。私が使用しているバージョンは4.0.0です。バージョンアップついでに此方でも検証してみようかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問に情報が追加されたので見ましたが、自分とバージョンが違ったようです。
新しいバージョンを私の方でも試してみました。

どうやら`CordovaWebview`の拡張型の使い方がひっかかっているようです。

先に修正箇所ですが2箇所あります。
`com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin`内
`src` > `android` > `WikitudePlugin.java`

`Line:754`付近
**Before**

```
((CordovaWebView)rootView).getView().clearFocus();
```

**After**

```
((CordovaWebView)rootView).clearFocus();
```

---

`Line:771`付近
**Before**

```
((CordovaWebView)rootView).handleResume(true);
```

**After**

```
((CordovaWebView)rootView).handleResume(true, true);
```

---

まずは`Line:754`から、View型を拡張してCordovaWebview型にしているので、
`getView()`でViewを取得しなくても大丈夫です。
(Monaca以外では分かりませんが……)
`Line:754`の方ですが、引数が一つ足りません。
そのためオーバーロードしようとして失敗してる感じですね。関数ありませんよみたいな。

Answer (score 0):

CordovaPluginのバージョンが4.1.0だからではないでしょうか？
3.5.1にして試してみる事をお勧めします。

詳細な回答が欲しい場合、
ビルド種別（ビルドOSや、デバッグ・リリースどちらかなど）や、プラグインの設定なども記述した方が良いと思います。

あとは`プラグインルート > www > WikitudePlugin.js`の中にある`this._sdkKey`にトライアル用でも良いのでKeyを入れとくと良いです。
ウォーターマークは出ますが、テストは出来るので……

追記：
ビルドメッセージを見ているとSDK Keyがないから動いてないのかもしれません。
(前に無効なライセンスキー入れてたら'undefined'とか出てたので分かりませんが……)
ライセンス自体は`Bundle ID`(`App ID`や`パッケージ名`とも言う)を元にしているので
自分のアプリでは2ライセンス＋Monacaデバッガー用で下記のようにライセンスを分けております。

```
/**
 *  This is the SDK Key, provided to you after you purchased the Wikitude SDK from http =//www.wikitude.com/store/.
 *  If you're having a trial version, leave this string empty.
 */
if(monaca.isAndroid){
    this._sdkKey = "android license";
}else if(monaca.isIOS){
    this._sdkKey = "ios license";
}

if(typeof this._sdkKey === 'undefined' || isDebug){
    this._sdkKey = "trial license";
}
```

なお、自分のアプリではiOS、Android共にビルドでき動作しております。

Comment: Cordovaのバージョンを3.5.1にして、パッケージ名をユニークにしましたが、現状同じエラーが出ます。　キーは最初から設定していました。（最初の質問に追加で説明入れました）